# How someone can be called as "Android Engineer"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Generally we have seen that a person writes his qualification as *an Engineer* or as *an Android Developer*.

But when he write like **"Android Engineer"** is it proper to use this word as a qualification?

Is this right to write like : ***"I am an Android Engineer"*** ?

Comment: If that's his job title, why not? People can call themselves a director, a manager, a doctor, a nurse, a clerk, etc., depending on their job title.

Comment: Actually I know that person and his job title is Android Developer,
And he is not an engineer anyways, but like to be called as an android engineer. So If he uses such title then is it proper to use?

Comment: People call themselves all sorts of things :) . (1) I'd like to know why you doubt the validity of Android Engineer as a title, even if it was self-applied. (2) Would it be different if he called himself a *software architect* or *coding guru* or something else? (3) Would a different name affect this - e.g. "Microsoft Engineer" or "Microsoft developer"? (These are not rhetorical questions - addressing the 3 points would help shed light on how you're framing your question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with the title **Android Engineer**. An **Engineer** is:

> 1. a person who designs, builds, or maintains engines, **machines**, or public works.

(Emphasis mine).

A person who designs, builds, or maintains Android hardware or software would be an engineer, one who specialises in Android systems, so they could certainly be called an **Android Engineer**. A Google search for the exact title "Android Engineer" returns 396,000 results, which is a pretty solid amount.

If you're not certain that the actual person in question has that skillset, that's a different matter; but there's certainly nothing wrong with the title itself.

Comment: We should note that in some jurisdictions, you can't legally call yourself an engineer without the proper degree or licensing.  In the US this is largely not the case (for example, "sanitation engineer" for "garbageman") but it is true elsewhere. I wonder if this is affecting the OP's take on the issue.

Comment: @stangdon In the US the equivalent is [Professional Engineer, or PE](https://www.nspe.org/resources/licensure/what-pe). The license is required to "prepare, sign and seal, and submit engineering plans and drawings to a public authority for approval, or seal engineering work for public and private clients."

Comment: @ColleenV, PE is a similar idea but not quite the same.  There is a level of practice that requires a degree and perhaps even an entry level license.  PE is an advanced credential and is required for certain tasks that involve public risk (like designing buildings).  It's analogous to medicine.  General practice requires a degree and a license but certain specialties require more advanced training and certification.